# Should the forward lookup zone target host FQDN be my application or web front end server?

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin

As the title suggests, when creating the forward lookup zone for hosting SharePoint Apps (Add-ins) should the target host be the FQDN of my application server or my web front end server?

My current farm has the following servers:

- SPA1 - Hosts Central Admin, UPSA etc... (spa1.example.com)
- SPW1 - Web front end server (spw1.example.com)
- SPDB1 - Sql Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The target host should be those that serve your content web applications to the end users.

This would usually be the web front end server in a farm with only a single web front end, or the NLB address if using multiple web front end servers.

Comment: That's what I thought. Does it make any difference that we are using Host-Named Site Collections? The default web application's site is using SSL on port 443 with no host name! Does this mean I would need to create another  web application to host the apps and bind this to a different ip address?

Comment: The instructions at https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mspfe/2013/01/31/how-to-configure-sharepoint-2013-on-premises-deployments-for-apps/ might help you. I've used apps with path-based site collections, but not host-named site collections. If you already have a web application without a host header, SharePoint won't allow you to create another one on the same IP address, so you'll need another IP address for the app listener web application. Have a look at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc424952.aspx#section4 for details on creating multiple web apps for use with HNSCs.

Comment: Note that this says that you cannot have multiple web applications with no host header (as far as SharePoint is concerned), so you create multiple web apps with host headers, then remove those host headers from IIS and bind each one to a different IP address on the server/NLB. This means that there is additional management getting it configured initially, and if you restore SharePoint at any point, the original host headers will go back into IIS and they will have to be manually removed again and the IP address binding reconfigured.

Comment: Thanks for the information. This confirms much of what I had read already. I was hoping for someone who has configured this way to verify. I'll accept this as the answer as the links are useful in the context of HNSC and the App Host.